# Toolbar package missing in sdk 6.0

Tags: java, blackberry

[image]

I can not use the toolbar lib even with sdk 6.0

I am using 6.0

Can anyone help me .. i m stuck here

Answer (score 0):

Is your project configured to use the BlackBerry 6.0 JRE System Library?